# Thread.Abort() creates deadlock when worker thread calls Dispatcher.Invoke()

Tags: c#, multithreading, deadlock

Two threads: main (GUI) and worker. The worker asks the main to update using `Dispatcher.Invoke(...)`. At some point, as a result of user intervention, I must abort the worker using `Thread1.Abort()`. But a deadlock seems to be created in this sequence:

1. T1 invokes for an action
2. main-thread aborts T1

[image]

I know, `Abort`ing is evil (what should I do ? insert `CheckIfCanceled()` every two lines ??), but assuming it's necessary - how can I prevent the deadlock ?

Comment: The point of using Dispatcher.Invoke() instead of Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() is that you can use its return value.  And that you can throw an exception and catch it in the thread.  Which gives you two excellent ways to stop the thread without having to abort it.

Comment: Do you really need to abort the thread immediately? Can't you just check `IsCancellationRequested` once (or a few times) in the primary loop of the thread?

Comment: @HansPassant, I don't understand what's your point. How can I stop the thread that way ? I have a long-running worker-thread, it asks the GUI for invocation from time to time, how can that help me ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to go anywhere, mentioning Dispatcher.Invoke() seems superfluous.  Use the Task class instead.  It supports cancellation with a CancellationToken, avoiding the need for the deadlock-prone Abort().  And lets you run code on the UI thread without having to use Dispatcher, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext.

Comment: Calling `Thread.Abort` is like stopping a car by shooting the driver in the head. The car will stop, but there's no telling what damage it'll do in the process.

Comment: OK, got it - just as I feared... not the right way to do it. Once again it was decided: `Thread.Abort()` is evil, `IsCancellationRequested` is the knight on the white horse. I accept the verdict.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows threading model you cant abort a thread from outside of its execution context. You should signal the worker thread to exit its worker method (then terminating the thread), to achieve this you can use something like CancellationToken or other cross thread flag. Thread.Abort() will throw an exception but it is not really guaranteed the time to do this specially when you use it with a locking multithread algorithm.

The best alternative for you is to call using `BeginInvoke()` and later use a `WaitHandle` to wait for the answer (this suspend the thread without spend CPU cycles waiting with a loop). When main thread attend your invoke request, it will signals through `WaitHandle` that thread can resume. Use a flag to indicate to the thread if it must to exit on resume.